# How to adjust discord bot trying to kick more than the bot should within a specified role?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I was trying to code a rolekick-bot for a specific reason, it works very well as it should, but as I tried to adjust the respond message for a successful kick, I noticed he tried to kick the exact amount of members who are in the Server (even if he didn't) he responded 7 times with 7 Members, and 6 times with 6 Members while kicked only the **one users** with the predefined Role.

```
if(!message.member.roles.some(r=>["Admin", "Moderator"].includes(r.name)) )
    return message.reply("You are not allowed to use this command.");
  console.log('rolekick');

  message.guild.members.forEach(member => {
    if (member.roles.find(role => role.name === 'IDLE')) member.kick()
      message.reply(`${member.user.tag} has been kicked by ${message.author.tag} because: IDLE`);

  });
}
```

thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` block in the `forEach` loop is not correct, you need to open a curly bracket right after the `if` condition and close it after `message.reply()`.

```js
  message.guild.members.forEach(member => {
    if (member.roles.find(role => role.name === 'IDLE')) {
      member.kick();
      message.reply(`${member.user.tag} has been kicked by ${message.author.tag} because: IDLE`);
    }
  });
```

Otherwise the `if` only applies to the following instruction (`member.kick()`) and the second statement applies for all members.